# Plug an iOS device into a computer, and then have the computer read its local files?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, macos

I'm developing a "two-part" app, where companion apps are installed on an iOS device and an OS X computer. What happens is:

1. iOS device gets connected to a computer via USB
2. Once connected, the iOS app writes some stuff to a local file.
3. Now how can I get the computer to read from that file? Would this require something like Bonjour, even though it is directly connected?

Comment: Sorry for the vote to close, didn't read carefully enough that this really was a programming related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going through iTunes and it's File Sharing mechanism or trying to mine backups (also created through syncing in iTunes), you're pretty much out of luck moving data between the iOS device and the computer via the USB connection.

Unfortunately, the only reasonable way to handle this sort of thing is via a wifi network connection between the iOS app and a service running on the Mac.  Bonjour is very handy for service location in getting the Mac/iOS device together.